# Playing music from two different sources

Tags: windows-10, audio

My question, more specifically, is about having programs like spotify, groove, etc. to play music from the speakers, while the sound from another application is played in my headset or something other than the speakers
Can it be done?

Comment: Are we supposed to guess what your operating system is?

Comment: Edited, sorry, forgot about it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course you can.

The paid one [CheVolume](http://www.chevolume.com/):

> CheVolume is a useful and reliable piece of software whose main purpose resides in offering you the means of outputting various audio application through a specific set of speakers, headphones or other similar devices.
>
> CheVolume is a handy tool that you can rely on for managing the output location for all your sound-emitting software, be they games, media players or web browsers, so you can enjoy multiple activities simultaneously.

The free alternative in [Github](https://github.com/audiorouterdev/audio-router):

> Audio Router
>
> I created a similar app that does exactly what CheVolume does, except this is free at least for now. I tried to make a public post about it here on /r/software, but apparently they don't allow any download links to unknown apps in a text post.

And a bonus one [IndieVolume](http://www.indievolume.com/) (very old software)

> IndieVolume makes Windows programs use separate volume controls independent of other Windows programs.
>
> Bespoke per-application volume, IndieVolume can also make Windows programs shut when GPS speaks, boost too silent sound, propagate sounds to multiple rooms in your apartment and many more.